# using task queue to send email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I wrote my first code with Google Task Queue Python API. It is supposed to send out an email every time URL is entered into the address bar. Although it shows a task in `default` task queue in my dashboard, I don't know why is it not executed even after an hour of initiating it.

queue-mail.py:-

```
class sendMail(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        mail.send_mail(
            'X@gmail.com',
        self.request.get('to'),
        self.request.get('subject'),
        self.request.get('body'))


taskqueue.add(url='/sendMail',params=dict(
    to='Y@hotmail.com',
subject = 'Testing task queues',
body = 'this is a message!'))
```

app.yaml:-

```
handlers:
 - url: /mail
   script: queue-mail.py
```

I invoked the code as: `appid.appspot.com/mail`

Comment: When I click on run now. It displays a banner saying run command is successfully issued. But I still don't receive the mail.

Comment: Is this on the local development server or production server?  Have you checked your logs for exceptions?  As a note I'm not sure if it's a misformat, but the indentation on your `sendMail` method is wrong, mail.send_mail should be indented more under `post`

Comment: Production server. Indentation is correct in the code I deployed. I've incorporated the same in the code I wrote here.

Comment: Have you defined a handler for the url `/sendMail`?  I don't see it in your app.yaml.

Comment: Is there a need to define handler when url is same as the class name? I did that before, but faced the same issues. I removed it to make my code compact.

Comment: Yes.  As it stands, your command `taskqueue.add(url='/sendMail' ...` is sending a request to the url `/sendMail`; how will the task get executed if your app doesn't know what to handle that url with?  Check your production logs for exceptions, it might prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as your problem is solved, I figured I'd post an official answer.  `post` worked while `get` didn't because that is the default method for task queue.  If you look at the [function documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/functions.html), one of the kwargs is method, in which you can specify get/post/etc, but as you didn't in your code, it defaulted to post.  As a side note, you probably didn't see a 404 for a missing handler, but a 405 for "method not allowed" (since the task queue was trying to send a post request to a handler that didn't have a post function defined)

Comment: why is it that `self.response.get` works even in a `post` method. Are these two independent things? Is there a way to see live logs. They are delayed by roughly half an hour, i guess.

Comment: Do you mean `self.request.get`?  The `get` function doesn't refer to the http method, it's just a generic python thing for retrieving values.  It's useful to do `self.request.get(x, None)` which will return None if x does not exist (or some other default you want).  Logs on your console are live; they aren't "delayed" or anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the section of the docs regarding [how to use the webapp framework](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html). You've defined a handler class, but you haven't defined a WSGI app for it, or invoked it in your script. As a result, your handler code will never get run.

Since you've put the code to enqueue the task at the module level, and haven't defined a `main()` function, every time a request is sent to the module, it will execute that code - so all your code does is enqueue the same task, over and over again, without actually doing anything. You need to separate the code to enqueue the task from the code that executes it, and put the enqueueing code in another handler that you invoke from a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think `send_mail` sends the task to the mail service which queues the task of sending the email. Therefore i'm not sure if `taskqueue.add()` will be any faster than `send_mail()`.
(assuming your email task doesn't do any RPC calls etc).